# Condition on a map key in update using datastax cassandra driver

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I want to create a query like

`UPDATE foo set map_clm['bar'] = 'biz' where id = 7 if map_clm['boo'] = 'bang';`

using QueryBuilder of Datastax's java driver for cassandra. I can create Assignment using something like `QueryBuilder.put("map_clm", "bar", "biz")`, but I am stuck in  creating a clause for IF Condition `map_clm['boo'] = 'bang'`. Is there anyway to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, most straightforward way will be to use `raw` function and put your `if` condition into it. But you need to be careful with escaping of arguments if you aren't using bindings.

Comment: QueryBuilder uses `?` in query string and sends unescaped data in CQL frame for string and epoch time for timestamp column. I want that.